# Computing GLCM with OrfeoToolBox?

Tags: orfeo-toolbox

I want to compute Haralick texture features with OrfeoToolBox with 90 ° orientation and a distance of 1. According to this [post](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!msg/otb-users/Z9XQLoYnnoo/ACWZunRhGgAJ):

```
displacement = sqrt(xoffset^2+yoffset^2) 
orientation = atan(yoffset/xoffset)
```

Answer (score 1):

you can use otb application HaralickTextureExtraction to compute GLCM with orfeo.

Offset are defined in a cartesian system (like in ITK) so 90° means an offset of (0,-1)

Check this discussion on itk mailing list which will gives you more detail explanation:

http://itk-users.7.n7.nabble.com/ITK-users-Offset-directions-td34274.html